# Change foreground color of "Go to declaration" in IntelliJ Editor

Tags: intellij-idea

How to change the foreground color in IntelliJ when you press : "CTRL + LEFT MOUSE CLICK" (Go to declaration) on a word (Default color is dark blue)

There is nothing in : FILE | SETTINGS | COLORS & FONT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment, please [vote for the existing feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-22469).